# Where does Visual Studio 2010 put the MSBuild logs?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

Where does Visual Studio 2010 put the MSBuild logs? I'm not even sure what they would be called. Any ideas?

Edit:  This is C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When running VS from the command line you can use the `/out` switch to determine where the build logs should be placed. Sample:

```
devenv.exe /rebuild Release "MyProject.sln" /out "MyProject.log"
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

I have the feeling you mean "where does VS put the build logs *when compiling from within VS*" and not from the command line, but this might still help.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly it. I have an issue with different versions of the same assembly going on and the suggestion was to look in the build logs.

Comment: This answer does not explain where Visual Studio (MSBuild, whatever, it's all the same to me) puts its build logs.  There used to be a link you could click in the output window to view the build log, but for some reason I don't see this anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that a log is only generated if you run devenv.exe with the /out switch and specify the log path.